# How do I redirect a user to the page they initially came from before being prompted to login with Auth0?

Tags: redirect, oauth, wordpress, auth0

I am using the `Auth0` plugin on WordPress, and it seems that there is only one field in the settings to set the URL users are redirected to after logging in. However, I want to have them return to the page they were on prior to logging in (i.e., my WordPress site has multiple protected pages from which users are prompted to login with Auth0). 

*How do I make the redirect URL dynamic, or simply set it to the page they were previously on (the protected page)?*

I've tried some redirect plugins but it seems that `Auth0 always overrides them`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solution can be found here: https://github.com/kevinvess/wp-force-login/issues/14

I installed the Force Login WordPress plugin (which protects all the pages on the site by default) and I whitelisted the homepage and pages I did not want protected with Auth0. Using the fix provided in the link above, I was able to get the redirect working.